# Vimrc setting normal yanking/deleting pasting to copy to clipboard

Tags: vim

How do I set the vimrc in Vim to make the default register the clipboard? I basically want to change all keys that interact with the default register.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for

```
:set clipboard^=unnamedplus
```

All commands that take a register will now default to the clipboard, as if you had prepended `"+`.

Comment: I run that command in gvim it tells me E474: Invalid arguemnt: clipboard^=unnamedplus

Comment: You need at least Vim 7.3.151.

Comment: Now it runs. It works for pasting but it doesn't work for yanking.